# Tests repeats the code with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

My tests just repeats the code. For method

```java
public void start(Context context) {
    context.setA(CONST_A);
    context.setB(CONST_B);
    ...
}
```

I wrote test using Mockito

```java
@Test
public void testStart() throws Exception {
    Context mockContext = mock(Context.class);

    action.start(mockContext);

    verify(mockAction).setA(Action.CONST_A);
    verify(mockAction).setB(Action.CONST_B);
    ...
}
```

Or for

```java
public void act() {
   state.act();
}
```

test

```java
@Test
public void testAct() throws Exception {
    State mockState = mock(State.class);
    context.setState(mockState);

    context.act();

    verify(mockState).act();
}
```

Are such tests useful? Such methods need to be tested and how to test them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, you should not try to have a 100% test coverage in general. Having a high test coverage is good, having a perfect coverage is useless and wastes your time. Any method that just sets, gets or delegate work to another method should not be tested, because it will cost you much to write and even more when refactoring. Finally, it won't add more anti-regression value or any help for anyone using your API.

Prefer testing method with real intelligence, risky or sensitive. The cases you submitted are test more Mockito than your own code. This will take build time and won't help you.

Comment: If working in a team strict 100% coverage can avoid that a member misses a test because he judges the tested method as to primitive. However I agree (with you and Doni) that one should not test with verify because you only repeat the code you want to test.

Comment: I agree with you. "Test the method contract, not its implementation".

Answer (score 1):

Personally I don't consider `verify()` useful at all since it directly tests the implementation instead of the result of your method. This will give you false failures when you change the implementation while the result is still correct.

As to whether this is useful: there is no logic to test so no, it's not particularly useful.

Comment: According to Bob Martin mocking behaviour (i.e. with verify) is fragile. One better should test based on data.

Answer (score 1):

According to the comments I left in other answers

```
public void start(Context context) {
  context.setA(CONST_A);
  context.setB(CONST_B);
  ...
}
```

should not be tested with Mockito, rather

```
@Test
public void testStart() throws Exception {
   Context context = new Context();

   action.start(context);

   assertThat(context.getA(), equalTo(Action.CONST_A));
   assertThat(context.getB(), equalTo(Action.CONST_B));
}
```

Its not much different, but in comparison with verify it can also get true, if start manages to reach this state without calling a setter or getter.